# getConstructor with no parameters

Tags: java, getconstructor

I can't seem to use `getConstructor` for constructors with no parameters.

I keep getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: classname.<init>()
```

Here is the code:

```
interface InfoInterface {
    String getClassName();
    String getMethodName();
    String getArgument();
}

class asa implements InfoInterface {
    @Override
    public String getClassName() {
        return ("jeden");
    }
    @Override
    public String getMethodName() {
        return ("metoda");
    }
    @Override
    public String getArgument() {
        return ("krzyk");
    }
}

class Jeden {
    Jeden() {
        System.out.println("konstruktor");
    }

    public void Metoda(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}

class Start {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        if (argv.length == 0) {
            System.err.println("Uzycie programu: java Start nazwa_klasy nazwa_klasy2...");
            return;
        }

        try {
            for (int x = 0; x < argv.length; x++) {
                Class<?> c = Class.forName(argv[x]);
                InfoInterface d = (InfoInterface) c.newInstance();
                String klasa = d.getClassName();
                String metoda = d.getMethodName();
                String argument = d.getArgument();

                Class<?> o = Class.forName(klasa);
                // o.newInstance();

                Constructor<?> oCon = o.getConstructor();
                System.out.println("ASD");
                Class<?> p = (Class<?>) oCon.newInstance();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
}
```

`o.newInstance();` prints `"konstruktor"` without problems.

Comment: has class o got any contructors in it? By default there is a no args one but as soon as you declare a constructor that has parameters then you will need to explicitly declare a no args one

Comment: It has only one, no args constructor. It work when I change it for one using string as argument and change the getConstructor accordingly.

I am told to use reflections, that's the point of this code

Comment: I think providing more code would be great

Comment: I updated the code for more info

Comment: Is `jeden` declared as an inner class? You should show all your code...

Comment: here is the rest of the code I got so far

Comment: are both classes in the same file?

Comment: Well, `return("jeden");` is not the proper way to return "something".

Comment: @Tom The brackets are redundant, but it works. Try it.

Comment: @pbabcdefp Yes it might work, but the parenthese suggest a method call, but this is not the case. It distracts a bit.

Comment: @RNJ: works when we add no-arg constructor in addition to the parameterized-constructor.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem is clear when you read the [javadoc of `.getConstructor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor-java.lang.Class...-):

> Returns a Constructor object that reflects the specified **public** constructor of the class represented by this Class object.

Emphasis mine.

In your code, the constructor is not public!

Example:

```
// Note: class is NOT public -- its default constructor won't be either
final class Test
{
    public static void main(final String... args)
        throws NoSuchMethodException
    {
        // throws NoSuchMethodException
        Test.class.getConstructor();
    }
}
```

Obligatory [link to an SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13541412) which also gives the JLS reference. In particular, note that the default constructor has the same access modifier as the class.

Comment: @fge: works when we add no-arg constructor in addition to the parameterized-constructor.

Answer (score 3):

It seems as if your class provides a constructor that is *NOT* a default constructor. The call to getConstructor() without parameters requires the class to have a default constructor. The following test illustrates this.

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class ConstructorTest {
    public static class ClassWithParameterizedConstructor {
        public ClassWithParameterizedConstructor(final String param) {
            // A parameterized constructor, no default constructor exists
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testFoo() throws NoSuchMethodException {
        // Parameterized constructor lookup works fine
        ClassWithParameterizedConstructor.class.getConstructor(String.class);

        // This doesn't work since there is no default constructor
        ClassWithParameterizedConstructor.class.getConstructor();
    }
}
```

So, a possible solution is to either change the call to getConstructor() to include the correct type or to provide a default constructor on the object itself (but why would you do that?).

Answer (score 1):

Read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html

It seems that both classes Class and Constructor have the method newInstance the difference is that in the Class class you can only call newInstance with no arguments, so the called constructor must have an no arguments (this also brings a problem when you have more that one constructor).
The methoe newInstance in the Constructor class allows you to call the constructor with arguments also, notice that you can also use the method getConstructors instead of getConstructor that returns you all the class constructors and allows you to call the constructor method you want.

In this case, since you only have one constructor only and with no arguments, Class.newInstance works fine. To use the getConstructor to have the same result you'll need to add in the end oCon.newInstance();

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getDeclaredConstructors()` which returns an array of Constructor objects reflecting all the constructors declared by the class represented by this Class object

```java
class SomeClass{

    {
        System.out.println("I'am here!");
    }

}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(SomeClass.class.getDeclaredConstructors()));
        // returns public, protected, default (package) access, and private constructors

        // System.out.println(SomeClass.class.getConstructor());
        // in that case you got:
        // NoSuchMethodException: reflection.SomeClass.<init>()
        // because SomeClass don't have public constructor

        for (Constructor constructor : SomeClass.class.getDeclaredConstructors()){

            constructor.newInstance();
        }

    }
}
```

And if you have private constructor like this:

```java
class SomeClass{

    private SomeClass(String val){
        System.out.println(val);
    }

}
```

You have to set accessible for constructor:

```java
constructor.setAccessible(true);
```

And get something like this:

```java
class SomeClass{

    private SomeClass(String val){
        System.out.println(val);
    }

}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        for (Constructor constructor : SomeClass.class.getDeclaredConstructors()){
            // constructor.newInstance("some arg");    // java.lang.IllegalAccessException
            constructor.setAccessible(true);
            constructor.newInstance("some arg");
        }

    }
}
```

Note: if your class declared as `private` his default constructor must be `private` too.

And be careful with nonstatic-inner classes, which receives an outer class instance

Answer (score 0):

In this (somewhat convoluted) scenario, it's actually possible to get hold of the (non-public) constructor by replacing:

```
Constructor<?> oCon = o.getConstructor();
```

with

```
Constructor<?> oCon = o.getDeclaredConstructor();
```

The "default" visibility of the `Jeden` class (and its constructor) makes it accessible to the `Start` class, since it's defined in the same package.