# Flink read custom types - implicit value error: `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init>()`

Tags: scala, avro, apache-flink

I am trying to read `avro` file with case class: `UserItemIds` that includes case class type: `User` , `sbt` and `scala 2.11`

```
case class User(id: Long, description: String)

case class UserItemIds(user: User, itemIds: List[Long])


val UserItemIdsInputStream = env.createInput(new AvroInputFormat[UserItemIds](user_item_ids_In, classOf[UserItemIds]))

UserItemIdsInputStream.print()
```

but receive: Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: schema.User.<init>()
```

Can anyone guide me how to work with these types please? This example is with `avro` files, but this could be `parquet` or any custom `DB` input.

Do I need to use `TypeInformation` ? ex:, if yes how to do so?

```
 val tupleInfo: TypeInformation[(User, List[Long])] = createTypeInformation[(User, List[Long])]
```

I also saw `env.registerType()` , does it relate to the issue at all? Any help is greatly appreciated.

I found the solution to this `java error` as [Adding a default constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023870/java-lang-nosuchmethodexception-userauth-user-init) in this case I added factory method to `scala` `case class` by adding it to the companion object

```
object UserItemIds{
case class UserItemIds(
                      user: User,
                      itemIds: List[Long])
       def apply(user:User,itemIds:List[Long]) = new 
       UserItemIds(user,itemIds)}
```

but this has not resolved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a default constructor for the `User` and `UserItemIds` type. This could look the following way:

```scala
case class User(id: Long, description: String) {
  def this() = this(0L, "")
}

case class UserItemIds(user: User, itemIds: List[Long]) {
  def this() = this(new User(), List())
}
```